# Cmake generator expression: how to get TARGET_FILE property on list of targets

Tags: cmake

I am creating a custom command that packages a list of targets into a proprietary package. A simplified version is show below.

I cannot figure out how to convert the list of targets into a list of paths to the executables. This is turning out to be harder than I expected it to be, which means I'm probably headed in the wrong direction.

Looking forward to some suggestions on how to proceed.

Thank you in advance for your support!

```
function(package_targets name  targets)

  add_custom_command(OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${name}"
    # How to make a list of paths from ${targets) using the $<TARGET_FILE:tgt> property?
    COMMAND "${PACKAGER_EXE}" "$<GENERATOR_EXPRESSION_TO_BE_CREATED_HERE>"
    DEPENDS ${targets}
    VERBATIM)
    #COMMAND_EXPAND_LISTS)

  add_custom_target(${name} ALL
    DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${name}")

endfunction(package_targets)
```

Comment: How do you cal the function? What is the value of `targets`? Just iterate over targets, accumulate them with `$<TARGET_FILE:${target}>` and call add_custom_command. Please show how are you calling the function and what `COMMAND` the function should generate (show input and expected output).

Comment: Thanks! I was trying too hard to make this work within the custom command.  This approach works.   As suggested, I iterated over the list of targets and created the generator expression that is used in the custom command.

Comment: If you found a working solution, please post it as an answer post, so that future visitors to your question can see how you resolved the issue.